# Read txt file and print after split action is not printing array value

Tags: java

I am trying to read txt file and then store splitted value in then array, and print all txt file value. But it is not printing the values.

This is how txt file value display as below:

```
"1675683811","590483002"
"2002199221","876015525"
```

Following are my code:

```
String st;
BufferedReader Br = null;
File objFile = new File("C:\\DATA\\File.txt");
Br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(objFile));
while ((st = Br.readLine()) != null) {
    String value = st.replace("\"", "");
    String[] arraylist = StringUtils.split(value, ",");                     
    for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
        System.out.println(arraylist[i]);
    }
}                   
Br.close();
```

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by "This is how txt file value display"? Do you mean that below it is content of `File.txt` file? If yes I can't reproduce your problem (I am getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` since `i <= 59` would result in `arraylist[2]` which isn't valid index for array of length 2).

Comment: @Pshemo - You are right. Since, I haven't mentioned whole file which has 60 column. Just for example purpose, I provided only two column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try to write code like below. I changed declaration of split and also way of showing values, because your way could make exception at objects arraylist:

```
    String st;
    BufferedReader Br = null;
    File objFile = new File("C:\\data\\file.txt");
    Br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(objFile));
    while ((st = Br.readLine()) != null) {
        String value = st.replace("\"", "");
        String[] arraylist = value.split(",");                     
        for (String row : arraylist) {
            System.out.println(row);
        }
    }                   
    Br.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

A small change to your code, you can just use `String.split` method and your for loop will always throws `ArrayOutOfBound` exception

```
String st;
    BufferedReader Br = null;
    File objFile = new File("/Users/a602782/input.txt");
    Br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(objFile));
    while ((st = Br.readLine()) != null) {
        String value = st.replace("\"", "");
        String[] arraylist = value.split(",");                    
        for (int i = 0; i <arraylist.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(arraylist[i]);
        }
    }                   
    Br.close();
```

And if you want to print each digit on each line you can loop it again inside of for loop

```
String st;
    BufferedReader Br = null;
    File objFile = new File("/Users/a602782/input.txt");
    Br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(objFile));
    while ((st = Br.readLine()) != null) {
        String value = st.replace("\"", "");
        String[] arraylist = value.split(",");                    
        for (int i = 0; i <arraylist.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(arraylist[i]);
            for (char c:arraylist[i].toCharArray()) {
                System.out.println(c);
            }
        }
    }                   
    Br.close();
```